# How to find location of the DNS server and the Email server

Tags: linux, email, shell, dns

How do you find location of your DNS server and Email server in shell (Putty) for Linux server?

I tried cat /etc/resolv.conf but wasn't sure if these are DNS details.

Also how do I find out email server location for specific email for example admin@xxxx.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `/etc/resolv.conf` is usually the correct place for DNS details (however, `/etc/nsswitch.conf` tells the resolver library where to look).
2. You ask the administrator of the `xxxx.com` domain.

Comment: I am the admin of that xxxx.com domain so can I go to somewhere like http://my-addr.com/email_server_location/e-mail_box_server_location/locate_email_address_for_free.php to find this out?

Comment: No, there is no standard way to find out the address of an email server (that you can use for email submission). Of course the domain MX records will contain the external address of the incoming email server, but that may or may not work for internal submission.

Comment: So is there a way to find out location of email server in shell then?

Comment: Ok, see if `dig mx xxxx.com` does what you want. It might, but I'm not sure what you want at this point.

Comment: John, define what you mean by "email server".  Are you asking about MX hosts that receive incoming mail, or SMTP relays that let you send outbound email?  Be specific in your question.

Comment: sorry it's mx hosts that receive incoming mail